# java.lang.NullPointerException while adding text on actionbar icon

Tags: android, xml

I have `actionbar_badge_layout.xml` file under layout as:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="48dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="right" >

<!-- Menu Item Image -->
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/icon_back" />

<!-- Badge Count -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_notifcation_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="99"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_dark_material_light" />
```

Inside `res/menu_comment xml` I have :

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_add"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_menu_add"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/actionbar_badge_layout"
    android:title="Add"
    app:showAsAction="always">
</item>
```

Then inside my activity I have  `onCreateOptionsMenu()` as:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_comment, menu);

    RelativeLayout badgeLayout = (RelativeLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.action_add).getActionView();
    TextView t = (TextView)badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_notifcation_textview); //here I am getting null pointer exception

    t.setText("12");


    return true;

}
```

But I am getting NullPointer exception. Logcat gives me output as:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.RelativeLayout.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.mypackage.activities.ShowCommentsActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ShowCommentsActivity.java:77)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2820)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:275)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:276)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:79)
        at android.support.v7.widget.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:49)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:459)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:69)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

what is wrong in this code. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where are you closing the `RelativeLayout`?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="48dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="right" >

<!-- Menu Item Image -->
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/icon_back" />

<!-- Badge Count -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_notifcation_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="99"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_dark_material_light" />
```

Add `</RelativeLayout>` at the end of the `XML` file.

Also, try changing your

```
  <item
    android:id="@+id/action_add"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_menu_add"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/actionbar_badge_layout"
    android:title="Add"
    app:showAsAction="always">
</item>
```

to,

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_add"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_menu_add"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/actionbar_badge_layout"
    android:title="Add"
    app:showAsAction="always">
</item>
```

Comment: that is usually omitted while posting question :)

Comment: @Yuva Raj after chainging app:actionLayout="@layout/actionbar_badge_layout"  it works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to call below function from `onCreate()` :

```
private void setActiobarTitle(String title)
{
   View v = getActionbar().getCustomView();
   TextView t = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_notifcation_textview);
   t.setText("12");
}
```

**Note :** Also set `actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);` to enable custom layout in action bar.