# NullPointerException after replaceing actionbar with toolbar

Tags: android, menu, nullpointerexception, toolbar

I'm using  badge layout in one menu item

here is some menuItems

```
  <item
    android:id="@+id/action_rdvmed"
    android:title="@string/rdv"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_action_event"
    android:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_msg"
    android:title="@string/msg"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/badge_layout"  <!--this one causes the problem-->
    android:showAsAction="always" />
<item
android:id="@+id/action_actualiser"
android:title="@string/actualiser"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
android:showAsAction="always" />
```

i'm getting a null pointer exception in my onCreateOptionMenu

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_med, menu);
    this.MenuMed = menu;
    RelativeLayout badgeLayout = (RelativeLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.action_msg).getActionView();
    mCounter = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.hotlist_hot); //the error in this line
    imgMessage = (ImageView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.hotlist_bell);
    badgeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            listMessages.clear();
            msg();
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

and here is the part of muy onCreate methode whare i'm using toolbar

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_med);
    Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: A stack trace would help.

Comment: sorry i didn't put it because i don't think it helps look at the accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're facing the same problem as one user faced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697201/java-lang-nullpointerexception-while-adding-text-on-actionbar-icon/29697333#29697333).

The **trick** is you need to change your `android:actionLayout` to `app:actionLayout`.

So, change your

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_msg"
    android:title="@string/msg"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/badge_layout"
    android:showAsAction="always" />
```

to,

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_msg"
    android:title="@string/msg"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/badge_layout"
    android:showAsAction="always" />
```

Comment: just another question ..the "always"  doesn't work in toolbar ?

Comment: @CharefEddineMechalikh similarly change `android:showAsAction` to `app:showAsAction`.

Comment: aaah ok , but why we do that ? hhhhh you know this little "app:" cause that craches !